# Symfony 4 / MongoDB / Docker multiple entries when saving data

Tags: mongodb, symfony, docker, docker-compose, doctrine-odm

I'm using Symfony 4 and MongoDB with docker and i want to save a new document (only one) on my database but multiple entries are inserted.

.env file :

```
PROJECT_DIR=/var/www/movies
APACHE_PORT=8080
PHP_PORT=9000
MONGODB_USER=test
MONGODB_PASSWORD=test
MONGODB_HOST=mongo
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_DB=movies

MONGODB_URL=mongodb://${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}
```

doctrine_mongodb.yaml:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: true
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_URL)%'
            options:
                username: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_USER)%'
                password: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_PASSWORD)%'
    default_database: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_DB)%'
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Document'
                    prefix: 'App\Document'
                    alias: App
```

Controller index function:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/", name="base")
     */
    public function index(DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $movie = new Movie();
        $movie->setTitle("Test");
        $dm->persist($movie);
        $dm->flush();

        return $this->render('base/index.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the error with your current solution?

Comment: Maybe you refresh the page multiple time. It this case, you will insert a movie object on every page refresh.

Comment: On my profiler, i have only one insert but in my database i have two rows inserted. And i tried also not refreshing page after deleting all data, i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i resolved the problem.
I commented the following line that was hanging on my base.html.twig, which was calling again the localhost.

```
{# <link rel='stylesheet' id='quick-preset-css'  href='{{ asset('') }}' type='text/css' media='all' />#}
```